# Apple maps not opening on link

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

i am very new to iOS-Development. We are developing a WebApp with Cordova at the moment and we  need a plugin to open the native maps application when we click on a button. Our current implementation looks like this:

```
#import "Maps.h"

@implementation Maps

-(void)startNavigation:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{
   NSString* street = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString* town = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

   street = [street stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
   town = [town stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

   NSString* address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@, %@", street, town];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: address]];
}

@end
```

But it has no effect, although i can see that the adress-String is correctly. If I pass the town, everything is working fine... Any ideas?

Thanks

Wal

## edit:

Thanks I checked the String and it was not a valid URL. No i am escaping the String through

```
address = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@, %@", street, town];
```

would product 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=blah, blah" -- is that a valid URL (the space)?

you should confirm the application can open using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:someURL];
```